# Norm of functional on $L^4[0, 1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to calculate the norm of the operator
$$
\begin{align}
f: L^4[0, 1] &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
x &\mapsto \int_0^1 t^3x(t) dt
\end{align}
$$
I started off by estimating
$$
||fx||  
=   \left| \int_0^1 t^3x(t) dt \right| 
\le \int_0^1 |t^3x(t)| dt 
\stackrel{Hölder}{\le} \left( \int_0^1 t^{12} dt \right)^{\frac{1}{4}} ||x|| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{13}} ||x||
$$
So therefore I know that $||f|| \le \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{13}}$. Now I need to find some $x \in L^4[0, 1]$ such that
$$
||f|| \ge \frac{||fx||}{||x||} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{13}}
$$
But I can't find any. Am I overseeing something simple?

Comment: You cannot apply Holder's inequality with $p=q=4$. You need $\frac 1 p+\frac  1 q=1$.

Comment: Hint: when do we have equality in Holder's inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying Holder's inequality with $p=4$ and $q=\frac  4 3$ we se that $|f(x)| \leq 5^{-3/4} \|x||$.  Hence the norm is at most equal to $5^{-3/4}$. To see that equality holds just take $x(t)=t$. I will let you verify that $\frac {|f(x)|} {\|x\|} =5^{-3/4}$ in this case.

Note: The choice of $x(t)$ is dictated by the condition for equality in Holder's inequality.